# Select only table name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table which has the full location of the table (MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable). I want to select only the table name for this so that I can join it onto another table (MyTable).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: r u tried with alias??

Comment: Try a combination of `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING()`

Comment: You want to select a value and use that as table name to join it? Oh no! Don't do it and if you do  you need dynamic SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Parsename function

```
select parsename('MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable',1)
```

Query is

```
select parsename(column_name,1) as table_name from table
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it should work :

```
select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Name),1,CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Name)) - 1)) as table_name 
from Table
```